# New Generation Capacity not increasing

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-size

I have been looking at the logs from jstat (-gc option) and have found that our application is spending a large amount of time doing new generation collection.

We have set max heap size as 16gigs (no minimums).

These are the initial capacities according to the jstat log:

S0C: 2112
S1C: 2112
EC: 17024
OC: 63872

Throughout the rest of the day none of S0C, S1C, EC increase even though we seem to have a large number of new generation events and spend a lot of time doing it. Old Capacity increases however.

I ran a comparison test in UAT by setting -XX:NewSize=6G and the application performed much better (very few new generation events and much less time in GC overall)

My question is: why is the new generation capacity not increasing with our original settings? Is it expected that I have to allocate more memory initially?

We are using JVM Hotspot 1.6.

Here is grep for 'New' from JVM defaults:

```
uintx MaxNewSize                                = 18446744073709486080{product}
intx NewRatio                                  = 2               {product}
uintx NewSize                                   = 1310720         {product}
uintx NewSizeThreadIncrease                     = 5320            {pd product}
intx PartialPeelNewPhiDelta                    = 0               {C2 product}
bool UseNewLongLShift                          = false           {product}
bool UseParNewGC                               = false           {product}
```

Comment: Which GC settings are you using? Sizing policies depend on the GC implementation being used. Maybe dump settings via -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal

Comment: These are the settings:-Xmx16384M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from certain about CMS ergonomics on hotspot 1.6, but maybe you have to enable the adaptive sizing policy and tune related options if you want hotspot to dynamically move the boundary of the young generation.

Alternatively upgrade to a newer JVM and try using G1GC, which definitely supports adaptive sizing.

It also might be that CMS doesn't use the full available size for the new generation because otherwise it couldn't meet some of its goals, e.g. the minor gc pause time goal. Make sure it's using a multi-threaded GC for the new generation, not the serial one.

I recommend enabling verbose GC logging and looking at what it does for minor generations.